# SELECT WHERE field!=value how it's done in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I can't find the answer since searching mysql NOT in google is a nightmare (even with the quotes).

I need to make a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field=value AND field2!=value2 AND field3!=value3
```

How it is done? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
        ((field = value) AND  
        (field2 <> value2) AND 
        (field3 <> value3))
```

If you're dealing with `NULL`, you have to do two things:

1. Use `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`
2. Declare `NULL` values to a dummy value.

SQL Cannot compare nulls.

To do that:

```
SET @value = ISNULL(@value, -1);
```

Comment: typo there I think... field3 <> field3 will always evaluate to a non-match won't it ;)

Comment: I had copied the Author's original post before he edited it. So that's why that was there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do exactly what you wrote, but use `<>` instead of `!=`

Perhaps the answer depends on what "value" is?  For example, for an integer 123 `value` would be `123`; for a string "foobar" `value` would be `'foobar'`.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried the `<>` operator

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = value AND field2 <> value2
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried "<>"?  it works in Delphi